# How to combine the text from 2 database column and insert the result in another column?

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to write a code where i can combine the first letter of column 1 in my database to the text of column 2 and insert the result in another column

basically this is what i want to happen

from

```
first_name    last_name    username
Lorem         Ipsum
```

into

```
first_name    last_name    username
Lorem         Ipsum        lipsum
```

what is the best way to handle this?

thanks in advance

Comment: `+1` for adding sample record with desired result. making it more descriptive :D

Comment: I think it isn't the best way to create an username because what happens after a change of first or last name? And why you want to save the combined name in the database? You can generate it again and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET username = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(LOWER(first_name),1,1),LOWER(last_name))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb5a9/1)

Comment: thanks for the reply
but what if i want to loop it with every row in my database?

is this code going to work?


$result=mysql_query(select * from tablename)

while($result){

UPDATE tableName

SET username= CONCAT(SUBSTRING(first_name,1,1),last_name)

}

is this correct?